# how to return 0 instead of null in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a huge problem in my code. I'm trying to return 0 if the wanted row returns null (which mean no data match the search criteria)

My query is:

```
$total7 = DB::table('agencies')
->join('users' , 'users.id' , '=' , 'agencies.user_id')
->join('user_addresses' , 'user_addresses.user_id' , '=' , 'users.id')
->join('cities' , 'cities.id' , '=' , 'user_addresses.city_id')
->join('country_states', 'country_states.id' , '=' , 'cities.state_id')
->select('agencies.id as agenID ','country_states.name as sName', DB::raw('count(agencies.id) as agencount') , 'agencies.created_at as agencreate' )
->where ('country_states.name','=','Capital Governorate')
->whereNULL ('agencies.id')
->whereBetween('agencies.created_at' , ['2017-01-01' , '2017-03-31'] )
->groupBy(DB::raw("MONTH(agencies.created_at)") , 'country_states.name')
->get();
```

this statement should return 0,0,2 but now it returns nothing. 
I want it to search throw the specified month range (3 months) and return the value if exists or 0 if no value.
I tried `IFNULL` but nothing.
Any help?

Comment: ->whereNULL ('agencies.id')

I dont understand this part really. if ID is an auto increment value why do  you check if it is null or not ? it will never be null

Comment: @Rodrane I'm trying to get any parameter that makes my statement work as I want. If no id for this governorate in this month, return zero.

Comment: well after you finish your query just do simple if (!$result)  ?

Answer (score 1):

```
    if(!$total7) {
      $result = 0;
     }
```

Then use `$result` variable where you want, in your controller or your blade file

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the count for the collection : `$total7->count();`
`

Comment: it shows me only the count of returned values not what I need which is go throw the first month, if there is value, print it, if not give me zero.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it from the query:

Use IFNULL:

IFNULL(fieldname, 0)

Comment: I'm not getting how to use IFNULL because it test it before and nothing worthy happened

Answer (score 0):

You can use the php function count:

```
 count($total7)
```

It will give you 0 when there is a null collection 
Check the first example:
http://php.net/manual/es/function.count.php

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE FOR ANSWER:**

I changed the query in terms to return what I need only which is

```
count(agencies.id)
```

So the query was with the code for output is:

```
 $countt = 3;
$ii = 1;
do{

                  $total7 = DB::table('agencies')
->join('users' , 'users.id' , '=' , 'agencies.user_id')
->join('user_addresses' , 'user_addresses.user_id' , '=' , 'users.id')
->join('cities' , 'cities.id' , '=' , 'user_addresses.city_id')
->join('country_states', 'country_states.id' , '=' , 'cities.state_id')
->select( DB::raw('ifnull(count(agencies.id),0) as agencount'))
->where ('country_states.name','=', $gover)
->whereMonth('agencies.created_at' ,  $ii)
->groupBy(DB::raw("MONTH(agencies.created_at)") , 'country_states.name')
->first();
if ( count($total7) == 0 ){
    echo '0,';
}else{
  echo $total7->agencount.',';
}


$ii++;

}while ($ii <= $countt);
```

`$gover` is a value come from another bigger `foreach` loop to loop throw all the governorate I have. `$ii` is a counter works as month counter to search throw the wanted range of months. do the query search until you reach the limit of wanted months (from 1 till 3 is 3 months).
if the current month has no value the returned values will be 0, if its zero, print it otherwise, give the returned value.

I thank all whom commented on this question. I own favor for you.